How to create a singleton class for amplitude?
I have the following amplitude code that initializes amplitude
import AmplitudeSwift
 
let amplitude = Amplitude(
    configuration: Configuration(
        apiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY"
    )
)
 

The problem is I have to call this code in every file to use amplitude. Is there a way to call it in one file so that I can do amplitude.sharedInstance.track() in other files?

Your question is a bit vague. Do you have the ability to modify the Amplitude class? If so, you could add plumbing to the class that creates a single instance.
Failing that, you could create a wrapper class that has the plumbing you need. Something like this:
import AmplitudeSwift

class AmplitudeFactory {

static var _amplitude: Amplitude?

static func amplitude(configuration: Configuration(
        apiKey: String )
   if let amplitude = self._amplitude {
      return amplitude
   } else {
       return Amplitude(
    configuration: Configuration(
        apiKey: apiKey
    )
}

(That's ugly because it won't handle the case where you change the Configuration object or the apiKey, but it gives the idea.)

I am not familiar with that library, but if it does not automatically have a shared instance you can use, you can declare one in an extension.

extension Amplitude
{
    static let sharedInstance = Amplitude(
        configuration: Configuration(
            apiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY"
        )
    )
}

// From anywhere in your module
Amplitude.sharedInstance.track()


